# getting error to display fetch data in table react native

Tags: javascript, error-handling, stack, fixed, array.prototype.map

I'm getting an error as undefined is not a function (near'...tableData.map').

how to fix this problem ? And i want to display fetch data inside the table.

my api format is something like:

### id  | FName | LName | Contact

### 01  |  Ash  | John  | 567828

02  | David | Wark  | 129352

i want my data in the table something similar this. how can i display fetch data inside the table in this format.

```
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(TD);

useEffect(() => {
  async function getData() {
    fetch('https://www.lampmonitor.com/lampmonitor/api/auth/web/lampControls?projectId=595&pageSize=50')
    .then(responce => responce.json())
    .then(data => {
      setTableData({data});
    });
  }

  getData();


return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
      <View>
        <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#C1C0B9'}}>
          <Row
            data={tableData.tableHead}
            widthArr={tableData.widthArr}
            style={styles.header}
            textStyle={styles.text}
          />
        </Table>
        <ScrollView style={styles.dataWrapper}>
          <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#C1C0B9'}}>
            {tableData.map((rowData, index) => (
              <Rows
                key={index}
                data={rowData}
                widthArr={tableData.widthArr}
                 style={[
                   styles.row,
                   index % 2 && {backgroundColor: '#F7F6E7'},
                 ]}
                textStyle={styles.text}
              />
            ))}
          </Table>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  
  </View>
);
```

Comment: AnyOne Can Help Me On it. How to fetch data inside a raect-native table

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

`setTableData({data});`

try spreading the object data like so:

`setTableData({...data});`

This is due to you wrapping the return data object in another object. The object prototype does not have `map` property.

Make sure you check what the actual returned `data` value is, and ensure you format accordingly.

Comment: i have done what you suggest but still have the same error on screen.

Comment: @AkashGhosh  console.log the `data` value that's returned from the promise. What is the value?